# Returning a shared pointer

Tags: c++

In C++, if I return a shared/unique ptr from a function, does it return by value? Ie

```
shared_ptr<CLASS> function_f(){
   auto p = make_shared<CLASS>(5);
   return p;
}
```

So what happens? Is the pointer inside dynamically allocated? If I return this, do I have 2 pointers pointing to the same thing?

Comment: The way you defined it, `p` is not a pointer.

Comment: The `std::shared_ptr<CLASS>` ***object*** is returned by value.

Answer (score 5):

The `shared_ptr` itself is returned by value. The `CLASS` object that it points to is dynamically allocated and therefore not copied.

You may briefly have two `shared_ptr`s to the same object (except for RVO, so in practice you probably won't), but by design of the `shared_ptr` class, this is not a problem.

Comment: And then when this method goes out of scope, `p` itself is deleted? So we only have a reference count of 1?

Comment: Yes, `p` is local to the function scope. The code you're showing is correct and idiomatic use of `shared_ptr`.